# Auto update label.content when i press a button in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created an application where i have there labels. I need to update the label.content when i click the button.

XAML

```
                <Label x:Name="lblTaxExcise" Content="Excise" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,112" Grid.Row="2" Width="47" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <Label x:Name="lblTaxEdu" Content="Edu. Cess" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,78" Grid.Row="2" Width="68" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <Label x:Name="lblTaxVat" Content="VAT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,44" Grid.Row="2" Width="35" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

C#

```
        SqlCeCommand com1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ExciseTax, EduCessTax, VatTax FROM Tax_Master", con);
        SqlCeDataReader dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            Excise = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]);
            EduCess = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[1]);
            Vat = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[2]);
        }
        lblTaxExcise.Content = "Excise @ " + Excise;
        lblTaxEdu.Content = "Edu. Cess @ " + EduCess;
        lblTaxVat.Content = "VAT @ " + Vat;
```

Part of the value is fetched from the database.

Comment: And the problem or the error you are getting is ........?

Comment: What are you getting error?

Comment: No error. Its not updating .

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on your `while` statement does your `Excise`, `EduCess` and `Vat` variables have any data in them?  The only other thing that I can see is that you have set your labels to a fixed width and your data will exceed it, you can either remove your Width, or set it to Auto

Comment: yes @MarkHall. They have default texts. I need to update their text when i press an "Add Product" button. Actually i code is OK, i assume. I have heard about background worker or something like that. I am not sure exactly how to achieve.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN I do not have a database setup, but your code does work in updating the labels in the Test that I made, just make sure your label can hold your values, see my last comment. In closer looking at your comment, I was not talking about your labels, I was talking about the variables you are filling with your Select statement

Comment: Yes , i checked again @MarkHall. I had declared them as constants at the top. double Excise = 14;
        double EduCess = 2;
        double Vat = 4;

Comment: Thanks @MarkHall. The thing was in there what you said. The width of labels wheren't auto. I changed and it worked.. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the width of the lable.It should work

```
   <Label x:Name="lblTaxExcise" Content="Excise" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,112" Grid.Row="2" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
   <Label x:Name="lblTaxEdu" Content="Edu. Cess" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,78" Grid.Row="2" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
   <Label x:Name="lblTaxVat" Content="VAT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,44" Grid.Row="2" Height="29" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the labels width property to auto.